# Not able to download and install go project

Tags: git, go, ssh

I am a beginner to go languague and trying to download and install goa-cellar project. But I am not able to install using ssh or https github link

1.**go get git@github.com:goadesign/goa-cellar.git**

```
package git@github.com:goadesign/goa-cellar.git: unrecognized import    path "git@github.com:goadesign/goa-cellar.git" (https fetch: Get    https://git@github.com:goadesign/goa-cellar.git?go-get=1: dial tcp:    unknown port tcp/goadesign)
```

2.**go get https://github.com/goadesign/goa-cellar.git**

```
package https:/github.com/goadesign/goa-cellar.git: "https://" not allowed in import path
```

Kindly help me how to solve this ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Install the package without to include the protocol (http/https).

```
go get github.com/goadesign/goa-cellar
```

Please be aware that you need to set the `GOPATH` environment variable. If you are not sure how to do that here is an article: https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH.

Comment: You want to remove the `.git` as well

Comment: WARNING: if using this command before go version 1.5 [your system was compromised](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9637)